# RVM trying to load old Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm

**UPDATE:** I just quit all instances of Terminal and opened a new window, and apparently the message is not showing anymore.

I uninstalled `ruby-2.1.0`, installed `ruby-2.1.3` and made it the default with RVM on Mac OS X.

Now everytime I open a new terminal window I see this:

```
ruby-2.1.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.1.0'
```

I looked on `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and `.rvmrc`, but I don't see anything trying to use `ruby-2.1.0`. I also updated the `.ruby-version` files.

`rvm list` shows `ruby-2.1.3` as the current and default ruby.

How do I stop that message from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go into a Rails project directory in your terminal, RVM looks up the `.ruby-version` file and if it finds it, it checks the Ruby version specified inside this file, then if that Ruby version is not installed on your system by RVM, it gives you the message you are getting.

This is actually very helpful, allowing to know your project is using a Ruby version which is not installed on your system

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I already did this. I just quit all instances of Terminal and opened a new one and apparently the message stoped showing. I updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't stop showing if you navigate to an old Rails project directory which uses `ruby-2.1.0`, can you try that ?

Comment: In this case it shows up as expected. The problem was that it was appearing whenever I opened a new tab or window, even if the folder didn't have a `.ruby-version` file.

Comment: Ok great, please accept my answer if you are happy with it :=/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to just quit all instances of Terminal and reopen it.

If anyone else is having this problem, check also Ali's answer regarding the `.ruby-version` file.